# Combinatorics problem using counting techniques for a word problem

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> **How many words of $4$ different letters can be created if $2$ of the $4$ letters are known ?**

I've counted the number of possibilities of the letters that can be rearranged and then I've multiplied the amount of letters that can be chosen from the alphabet.

So I've came to the conclusion the answer must be

$24 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 13248$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is not correct.

**Method 1:**  There are $4$ ways to place the known letter which appears first in an alphabetical list, $3$ ways to place the other known letter, $24$ ways to select a letter to fill the first of the remaining two positions, and $23$ ways to fill the second of the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are
$$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 24 \cdot 23 = 6624$$
such words.

**Method 2:** We correct your attempt.  There is one way to select the two known letters, $\binom{24}{2}$ ways to select the other two letters, and $4!$ ways of arranging the four distinct letters, giving
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{24}{2}4! = 6624$$
such words.

**Note:**  When you chose the first unknown letter in $24$ ways, then chose the second unknown letter in $23$ ways, you counted each selection twice since if the known letters are $A$ and $B$, selecting $C$ as the first unknown letter and $D$ as the second unknown letter produces the same set of words as selecting $D$ as the first unknown letter and $C$ as the second unknown letter when you permute the letters $ABCD$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the solution.